# Switch case basic

Tags: c, switch-statement

Below mentioned program is a basic form of switch case. I'm trying to print the macros variable in the out put. For more details refer the output. Its not printing the macros variable.

Switch case

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define a 4
#define d 5

int main()
{
    int x = 10;

    switch (x)
    {
        case a: printf("Number is 40");
        break;

        case d: printf("Number is 50");
        break;

        default: printf("Default case");
        break;
    }
}
```

Expect:
Number is 40

Actual:
Default case

---

Kindly refer the Point 1 & 2.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define a 4
#define d 5

int main()
{
    int x = 4; //(Point1)Here I'm declared the x value as 4 which is equal to the above defined one of the macros. Hence the output has printed the expected value as said by @ed heal. 

    switch (x)
    {
        case a: printf("Number is 40"); //(Point 2)User can be expect anything as dummy output.
        break;

        case d: printf("Number is 50");
        break;

        default: printf("Default case");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect this? `a` = 4, `d` is 5 `x` is 10. BTW Start losing the love affair with the prepressor.

Comment: Your value is 10, case is 4...

Comment: if `a` literally is `4` and `x` is `10` why you expect `Number is 40` as output?

Comment: Equivalent to `if (x==4)....else if (x==5)....else printf("default case")` and since x is 10....

Comment: How on earth can you expect this to print 40?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting `x` to 10. You're switching on `x`, that is 10, and neither `a` nor `b` evaluate to 10, so the default case statement is used.